# I found this code for functional programming online. Is it considered functional programming if the array is being changed and if we are using loop?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
var map = (f, array) => {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        newArray[i] = f(array[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

An array called newArray is created inside the map function and it is being modified. Is it considered functional programming if we are changing properties of newArray and it is using for loop? Functional programming is not supposed to change values and loops are not allowed. This code was under functions in functional programming.

```
var things = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var newThings = map(v => v * 10, things);
```

I found this code here https://medium.com/@cscalfani/so-you-want-to-be-a-functional-programmer-part-4-18fbe3ea9e49

Answer (score 2):

Just read the 2-3 paragraphs of text that precede that code:

> This time we won’t mutate things:
>
> ```
> var newThings = [];
> for (var i = 0; i < things.length; ++i) {
>     newThings[i] = things[i] * 10;
> }
> console.log(newThings); // [10, 20, 30, 40]
> ```
>
> Okay, so we didn’t mutate things but technically we mutated newThings.
> For now, we’re going to overlook this. We are in Javascript after all.
> Once we move to a Functional Language, we won’t be able to mutate.
>
> The point here is to understand how these functions work and help us
> to reduce noise in our code.

So the author is aware of your point but is *"...going to overlook this."*.

The thing is that the author is defining a `map` function, when JavaScript at that time (2016) had already introduced a `map` method (and `filter`, `reduce`, `Array.from`,...). But imagining that such kind of function isn't available, there is not much else you can do in JavaScript than to push values to an array, or inject them with `newArray[i] =` .

The author's aim was to create *once* a function that could be criticized, and he remarks:

> ...But at least we don’t have to write that boilerplate code any more.

Now the author has something (`map`) that can be used in a truly functional way.

Why the author didn't use any of the available strategies in JavaScript that allow functional programming from the start? Possibly they wanted to take their readers slowly from imperative programming to functional programming without immediately jumping to the native methods and syntax that are functional from the start. We can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code violates the functional principle of immutability.
How bad this is in the end depends on your viewpoint - pragmatically speaking it does not make a big difference because it enables you to use map in a functional way.

This is one way to define `map` without violating immutability, using a recursive function:

```
const map = (f, array) => {
  if(!array.length) {
    return [];
  }
  const [head, ...tail] = array;
  const mappedHead = f(head);
  if(!tail.length) {
    return [mappedHead];
  }
  return [mappedHead, ...map(f, tail)];
}
```

This is an implementation that considers tail recursion:

```
const mapTailRecursive = (f, array, result = []) => {
  if(!array.length) {
    return result;
  }
  const [head, ...tail] = array;
  const mappedHead = f(head);
  if(!tail.length) {
    return [...result, mappedHead];
  }
  return mapTailRecursive(f, tail, [...result, mappedHead]);
}
```